# UseOAuthBearerTokens vs UseOAuthBearerAuthentication

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, owin, asp.net-identity-2, katana

In our `Startup` class, I have configured the following auth server options:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/v1/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
};
```

After this, which option are we supposed to use to actually enable bearer authentication?  There seem to be two variations on the Internet.

**Option 1:**

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

**Option 2:**

```
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthServerOptions);
```

I have tested them both and the results are the same.

What are the difference between these options?  When are we supposed to use which?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `UseOAuthBearerTokens` extension method creates both the token server and the middleware to validate tokens for requests in the same application.

Pseudocode from source using reflector:

```
UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(); // authorization server middleware
UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(ApplicationOAuthBearerProvider); // application bearer token middleware           
UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(ExternalOAuthBearerProvider); // external bearer token middleware
```